# How does voltage increase the energy of the charges and the current separately?

Tags: electric-current, potential, voltage

A lot of people say that a battery converts chemical energy to electrical energy which is transferred by the charges to components in the circuit (such as bulbs).  This analogy doesn't make sense as it implies the current would decrease once it has passed through a component (when we know that current is the same everywhere.

Comment: Why does it follow that the current would decrease once it has passed through a component? I don't understand your reasoning. Don't the charges leaving the component have less potential energy than the charges entering the component?

Comment: I agree. I don’t understand the “it implies” either

Answer (score 0):

> This analogy doesn't make sense as it implies the current would decrease once it has passed through a component (when we know that current is the same everywhere.

This inference isn't correct.

The power transferred to a component is the product of the voltage across its terminals and the current through it. ($P = IV$).

So the same current does not always transfer the same power. If delivered at a lower voltage it will deliver less power.

And that is what happens in a circuit with (for example) a voltage source and two bulbs in series. The current is the same through the bulbs, but the voltage is dropped by the first bulb so that the second bulb receives only half the power produced by the source.

Answer (score 0):

Taking following as your main concern :

> the current would decrease once it has passed through a component (when we know that current is the same everywhere.)

Suppose a typical electric circuit with a battery hooked up to a light bulb. You are saying that How do we know if the current is the same everywhere? If the current were not the same all the way around ( for instance, during the first second after the switch is closed), then the charge would be piling up somewhere, and this is the crucial point, the electric field of this accumulating charge is in such a direction as to even out the flow.

Suppose, for instance, that the current into the bend is greater than the current out. Then positive charge piles up at the “knee,” and this produces a field aiming away from the kink. This field opposes the current flowing in (slowing it down) and promotes the current
flowing out (speeding it up) until these currents are equal, at which point there is no further accumulation of charge, and equilibrium is established. It’s a beautiful
a system, automatically self-correcting to keep the current uniform, and it does it
all so quickly that, in practice, you can safely assume the current is the same all
around the circuit, even in systems that oscillate at radio frequencies.

---

> A lot of people say that a battery converts chemical energy to electrical energy which is transferred by the charges to components in the circuit (such as bulbs).

Here note that the battery is a continuous source of electrical power. It produces a voltage difference between two terminals of the circuit which makes the current flow. If the suppose the battery is decaying due to some reason so that Voltage difference between the terminal get lower as time passes then the current also decrease as $V\propto R$.